# Push Notifications on iOS and Android for website

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, push-notification

I'm struggling with a scenario where I have a website that is accessed by Android and iOS(written in HTML/Javascript) where the customer is asking for push notifications for both platforms.

Is there anyone here with an idea on how to solve that for both platforms? I was thinking of packaging the website as an application using Cordova. I haven't tried it before so I am looking into that now. If there is any better suggestion then I would really appreciate to hear that.

Comment: You can use FCM for this follow this https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: But it is a website at the moment. Doesn't firebase just enable cloud messaging the app exists and is written in native code? The messaging system is already written, all I need is push notifications for it.

Comment: @why_vincent You are right, you cannot send FCM notifications to a application running in a browser on ios. Were you able to find any solution to your question?